# Run-time error. Integer convert to string

Tags: java, string, int, type-conversion

I am currently creating a program that returns the ordinal form of a number (1st, 2nd etc.). But when I run my program I get a runtime error.

I am suspecting that it has something to do with my converting from int to string, but I can't seem to find the source of the problem.

```
public void run() {
        ordinalform(5);
    }

    private String ordinalform(int num) {
        String number = Integer.toString(num);
        String correctWord ="";
        if((number.charAt(number.length()-2)=='1'
                && number.charAt(number.length()-1)=='1')){
            correctWord=number+"th";
        } else if (number.charAt(number.length()-2)=='1'
                && number.charAt(number.length()-1)=='2') {
            correctWord=number+"th";
        } else if ((number.charAt(number.length()-1)=='1'
                && number.charAt(number.length()-1)=='3')) {
            correctWord=number+"th";
        } else if(number.charAt(number.length()-1)=='1') {
            correctWord=number+"st";
        } else if(number.charAt(number.length()-1)=='2') {
            correctWord=number+"nd";
        } else if(number.charAt(number.length()-1)=='3') {
            correctWord=number+"rd";
        } else {
            correctWord=number+"th";
        }
        println(correctWord);
        return correctWord;
    }
}
```

The error: `Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
    at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:646)
    at StringTraining.ordinalform(StringTraining.java:17)
    at StringTraining.run(StringTraining.java:11)
    at acm.program.Program.runHook(Program.java:1568)
    at acm.program.Program.startRun(Program.java:1557)
    at acm.program.AppletStarter.run(Program.java:1895)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)`

Comment: Stack trace, please.

Comment: This is not a compile time error, but a runtime error by the way.

Comment: It is a run time error. Please update your descrption.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**EDIT:**

You are calling your method with the number 5 as a parameter :

```
ordinalform(5);
```

The first instruction that executes in the `ordinalform` function :

```
String number = Integer.toString(num);
```

This converts the variable `num` (equals 5) to a String. Now `number` is equal to "5". Notice that `number.length()` is equal to 1 now.

Next in your condition:

```
if((number.charAt(number.length()-2)=='1' && ....) { }
```

`number.length()` is equal to 1 (number == "5"). Therefore, `number.length() - 2` will be equal to -1. So technically, what you are trying to do is:

```
if((number.charAt( -1 )=='1' && ....) { }
```

And since there is no such thing as index -1, a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` is thrown, and the execution fails.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that please?

Comment: Ah I see it now. I thought that if the string was only 1 character long it would just ignore the "if((number.charAt(number.length()-2)=='1' && ....) { }" So how do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. What i needed was an extra condition in the three first loops.

```
public class StringTraining extends ConsoleProgram {

public void run() {
    ordinalform(5);
}

private String ordinalform(int num) {
    String number = Integer.toString(num);
    String correctWord ="";

    if(number.length()>1 && number.charAt(number.length()-2)=='1'
            && number.charAt(number.length()-1)=='1'){
            correctWord=number+"th";
    }else if(number.length()>1 && number.charAt(number.length()-2)=='1'
            && number.charAt(number.length()-1)=='2') {
            correctWord=number+"th";
    } else if (number.length()>1 && number.charAt(number.length()-2)=='1'
            && number.charAt(number.length()-1)=='3') {
        correctWord=number+"th";
    } else if(number.charAt(number.length()-1)=='1') {
        correctWord=number+"st";
    } else if(number.charAt(number.length()-1)=='2') {
        correctWord=number+"nd";
    } else if(number.charAt(number.length()-1)=='3') {
        correctWord=number+"rd";
    } else {
        correctWord=number+"th";
    }
    println(correctWord);
    return correctWord;
}
```

}